# How to write a function f("123")=123+12+23+1+2+3 as a recurrence relationship

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, numbers, number-theory

I'm wondering if someone can help me try to figure this out.

I want `f(str)` to take a string `str` of digits and return the sum of all substrings as numbers, and I want to write `f` as a function of itself so that I can try to solve this with memoization.

It's not jumping out at me as I stare at

```
        Solve("1") = 1
        Solve("2") = 2
        Solve("12") = 12 + 1 + 2
        Solve("29") = 29 + 2 + 9
        Solve("129") = 129 + 12 + 29 + 1 + 2 + 9
        Solve("293") = 293 + 29 + 93 + 2 + 9 + 3
        Solve("1293") = 1293 + 129 + 293 + 12 + 29 + 93 + 1 + 2 + 9 + 3
        Solve("2395") = 2395 + 239 + 395 + 23 + 39 + 95 + 2 + 3 + 9 + 5
        Solve("12395") = 12395 + 1239 + 2395 + 123 + 239 + 395 + 12 + 23 + 39 + 95 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 9 + 5
```

Comment: Could you show own attempts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to break `f` down into two functions.

Let `N[i]` be the `i`th digit of the input. Let `T[i]` be the sum of substrings of the first `i-1` characters of the input. Let `B[i]` be the sum of suffixes of the first `i` characters of the input.

So if the input is "12395", then `B[3] = 9+39+239+1239`, and `T[3] = 123+12+23+1+2+3`.

The recurrence relations are:

```
T[0] = B[0] = 0
T[i+1] = T[i] + B[i]
B[i+1] = B[i]*10 + (i+1)*N[i]
```

The last line needs some explanation: the suffixes of the first `i+2` characters are the suffixes of the first `i+1` characters with the `N[i]` appended on the end, as well as the single-character string `N[i]`. The sum of these is `(B[i]*10+N[i]*i) + N[i]` which is the same as `B[i]*10+N[i]*(i+1)`.

Also `f(N) = T[len(N)] + B[len(N)]`.

This gives a short, linear-time, iterative solution, which you could consider to be a dynamic program:

```
def solve(n):
    rt, rb = 0, 0
    for i in xrange(len(n)):
        rt, rb = rt+rb, rb*10+(i+1)*int(n[i])
    return rt+rb

print solve("12395")
```

Comment: +1, very nice analysis, avoiding what seems to be the quadratic-time nature of the problem and yielding a linear-time solution. However, shouldn't that be `f(N) = T[len(N)-1] + B[len(N)-1]`? Your code seems to be correct and it uses my version of that equation for `f(N)`. Also, you may want to comment that your code is for Python 2.x, needing modification of `xrange` and `print` to work in Python 3.x.

Comment: You could make this work in both versions of Python by using `for i, c in enumerate(n):`, `int(c)` rather than `int(n[i])`, and `print(solve("12395"))`. The changes in the `for` block would also make it more pythonic. You also may want to change the parameter from `n` to something like `nstr` since its value is a string and not a numeric type. Still, an excellent answer on your part!

Comment: @RoryDaulton I changed the definitions of `T` and `B` to make the existing formula correct. You're right that the original version was off-by-one. I don't really mind about the py2/py3 difference -- if this were a python question I'd be more careful, but I think it's fine to avoid the quite-python-specific enumerate() and show code that's easy to convert to any other language.

Answer (score 3):

One way to look at this problem is to consider the contribution of each digit to the final sum.

For example, consider the digit `Di` at position `i` (from the end) in the number `xn-1…xi+1Diyi-1…y0`. (I used `x`, `D`, and `y` just to be able to talk about the digit positions.) If we look at all the substrings which contain `D` and sort them by the position of `D` from the end of the number, we'll see the following:

```
       D
      xD
     xxD
       …
   xx…xD
      Dy
     xDy
    xxDy
      …
  xx…xDy
     Dyy
    xDyy
   xxDyy
     …
 xx…xDyy
```

and so on.

In other words, D appears in every position from 0 to `i` once for each prefix length from 0 to `n-i-1` (inclusive), or a total of `n-i` times in each digit position. That means that its total contribution to the sum is `D*(n-i)` times the sum of the powers of 10 from `100` to `10i`. (As it happens, that sum is exactly `(10i+1−1)⁄9`.)

That leads to a slightly simpler version of the iteration proposed by Paul Hankin:

```python
def solve(n):
    ones = 0
    accum = 0
    for m in range(len(n),0,-1):
        ones = 10 * ones + 1
        accum += m * ones * int(n[m-1])
    return accum
```

By rearranging the sums in a different way, you can come up with this simple recursion, if you really really want a recursive solution:

```python
# Find the sum of the digits in a number represented as a string
digitSum = lambda n: sum(map(int, n))

# Recursive solution by summing suffixes:
solve2 = lambda n: solve2(n[1:]) + (10 * int(n) - digitSum(n))/9 if n else 0
```

In case it's not obvious, `10*n-digitSum(n)` is always divisible by 9, because:

1. `10*n == n + 9*n == (mod 9) n mod 9 + 0`
2. `digitSum(n) mod 9 == n mod 9`. (Because `10k == 1 mod n` for any `k`.)
3. Therefore `(10*n - digitSum(n)) mod 9 == (n - n) mod 9 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this pattern:

```
Solve("1") = f("1") = 1
Solve("12") = f("12") = 1 + 2 + 12 = f("1") + 2 + 12 
Solve("123") = f("123") = 1 + 2 + 12 + 3 + 23 + 123 = f("12") + 3 + 23 + 123 
Solve("1239") = f("1239") = 1 + 2 + 12 + 3 + 23 + 123 + 9 + 39 + 239 + 1239 = f("123") + 9 + 39 + 239 + 1239
Solve("12395") = f("12395") = 1 + 2 + 12 + 3 + 23 + 123 + 9 + 39 + 239 + 1239 + 5 + 95 + 395 + 2395 + 12395 = f("1239") + 5 + 95 + 395 + 2395 + 12395
```

To get the new terms, with `n` being the length of `str`, you are including the substrings made up of the 0-based index ranges of characters in `str`: `(n-1,n-1), (n-2,n-1), (n-3,n-1), ... (n-n, n-1)`.

You can write a function to get the sum of the integers formed from the substring index ranges. Calling that function `g(str)`, you can write the function recursively as `f(str) = f(str.substring(0, str.length - 1)) + g(str)` when `str.length > 1`, and the base case with `str.length == 1` would just return the integer value of `str`. (The parameters of `substring` are the start index of a character in `str` and the length of the resulting substring.)

For the example Solve("12395"), the recursive equation `f(str) = f(str.substring(0, str.length - 1)) + g(str)` yields:

```
f("12395") = 
f("1239") + g("12395") =
(f("123") + g("1239")) + g("12395") =
((f("12") + g("123")) + g("1239")) + g("12395") = 
(((f("1") + g("12")) + g("123")) + g("1239")) + g("12395") =
1 + (2 + 12) + (3 + 23 + 123) + (9 + 39 + 239 + 1239) + (5 + 95 + 395 + 2395 + 12395)
```